# How do I get the number of address lines of 12G * 64?

Tags: memory, ram

The example problems I'm seeing in the book gives me nice numbers where the size of the ram can easily fit into a power of 2, but this one doesn't.

The original question:
[image]

This is all I have:
[image]

I was thinking about splitting twelve into **2^3** and **2^2** then add them but I don't know? or would I just choose which ever ram is higher or lower like 12 is in-between 8 and 16?

Comment: How do you fit something into a box when you don't have exactly the right sized box? Obviously, you just use the next size up and live with the empty, unused space. Simple, no?

Comment: @DKNguyen true, i guess i'll go with 16G then